# Edit commands in iTerm2 with standard OS text keyboard/mouse controls

Tags: terminal, keyboard, mouse, iterm, command-line

I'm a heavy terminal user, but I'd like to be edit commands like I would in any other mac app, e.g.:

- select a portion of a command with the mouse and press backspace to delete it
- use shift+up to select all of a command to the start
- use the mouse to click and place the cursor (not in conjunction with holding modifier keys)

I've tried Preferences > Profiles > Keys > "Natural Text Editing" but it doesn't seem to work.

I appreciate that many people prefer to use terminal-specific bindings, e.g. vim/emacs modes, but I'd just like to be able to interact with a terminal like I'd interact with any other app.

Comment: what shell are you running? I pretty much do that, or most of it anyway.

Comment: I'm running fish and bash. `Shift+up` just prints `;2A`, and placing the cursor with the mouse only works if I hold down `option`.

Comment: I don't use the fish shell but bash seems to give me what I need. From the bash shell have you tried typing tcsh?  I use that too and maybe thats the key. I don't use the option key at all that I recall. I click and drag the mouse to select a command or part of a command on the screen.

Comment: Have you been able to try tcsh?  I'm just wondering if you're having any luck.

Answer (score 1):

I use the bash shell and do much of what you want. I use the mouse to select something and command-c to copy or command-v to paste. I can place the cursor wherever I want with mouse. Well it doesn't really move the cursor but I highlight what I want to copy or cut. The up and down arrows scrolls thru previous commands. Typing tcsh adds more functionality.